# How to consume webservice with complex ksoap2 mailing envelope correctly?

Tags: java, android

I need to send to the webservice that envelope:

```
` <? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
 <soap: Envelope xmlns: xsi = "http://wwwenter code here.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns: xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns: soap = "http : / / schemas.xmlsoap.org / soap / envelope / ">
    <soap:Body>
         <getCasesAsString xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
           <caseFilters> string </ caseFilters>
         </ getCasesAsString>
    </soap: Body>
 </soap: Envelope>`
```

Where "string" in `<caseFilters> string </ caseFilters>` filter should be replaced by that desire.

More like this

`

```
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
  <soap: Envelope xmlns: xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns: xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns: soap = "http : / / schemas.xmlsoap.org / soap / envelope / ">
     <soap:Body>
       <getCasesAsString xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <caseFilters>
            <processName>process_name</ processName>
          </ caseFilters>
       </ getCasesAsString>
     </ soap: Body>
  </ soap: Envelope>`
```

the most I was able to make it in this envelope:

`

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <v:Header />
    <v:Body>
       <getCasesAsString xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" id="o0" c:root="1">
         <caseFilters i:type="n0:Process" xmlns:n0="http://tempuri.org/">
           <processName i:type="d:string">PROCESS_NAME</processName>   
         </caseFilters>
       </getCasesAsString>
    </v:Body>
  </v:Envelope>`
```

But I get a server error, refusing the envelope, the following error:

`

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap: Server' faultstring:    System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The server could not process the request. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: invalid data at the root level. Line 1, position 1.
    in System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw (Exception e)
    in System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw (String res, String arg)
    in System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace ()
    in System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent ()
    in System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read ()
    in System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load (XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
    in System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load (XmlReader reader)
    in System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml (String xml)
    in BizAgi.Web.Services.CWorkflowSOAWrapper.getCasesAsString (String caseFilters)
    --- End of stack trace --- inner exception 'faultactor:' null 'detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node @ 4396c958`
```

I think these can be id = "o0" c: root = "1" or i: type = "n0: Process"

I need help to correctly assemble the envelope ...

someone there willing to help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your envelope XML looks OK, and also from the stack trace looks like `getCasesAsString()` is actually called. What is that XML you're trying to parse inside getCasesAsString()? Looks like it is not syntactically correct - or maybe it is, but you're using a weird parser which thinks differently.